# colorBackgroundCacheHint Resource not found

Tags: android

I added th below item under `<style name="mycutomDialog" parent="android:Theme.Light">` as theme. 
`<item name="colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>` 
However, Android complained that "colorBackgroundCacheHint resource not found that match the given attr. How could I define this attr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preface the attribute name with "android:".  This XML attribute is defined in the Android SDK, and thus the android namespace must be used.

```
<item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing android `<item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>`